# PHP: A Particular Page is Not Making its Session Variables Accessible in the Next Page

Tags: php

I have a sign up page and login page for my site. When a user sign up, I want some of his details be stored in **SESSIONS** so that it can be
accessible in the next page. This is working in the local server but it doesn't on a live server.

I have login.php and signup.php in the root directory and I also three folders in the root directory; **SIGNUP2** folder(this has signup2.php where the user
completes their sign up), **HOME** folder (this has home.php which is the home page of the site when a user successfully logs in) and **PROFILE** folder
(which details.php for viewing users' profile). The **PROFILE** has an `.htaccess` file in it and it is only used to rewrite urls related it.

From `login.php`, sessions are created if the user is validated and it redirects to `header("Location:http://www.example.com/home/home.php");`. This 
is working fine on the live server and the session data are used as expected. However, if a user is signing up in `signup.php`, sessions are also created when
his/her details are validated and redirects to `header("Location:http://www.example.com/signup2/signup2.php");` but session is returning empty array
via `print_r($_SESSION);`.

I created a file, `printSession.php` and store it in **home** folder. If I head to it `header("Location:http://www.example.com/home/printSession.php");`
it still print empty array via `print_r($_SESSION);` but if I redirect to it from `login.php`, it prints out the data fine.

All files have `session_start();` at the top. `print_r($_SESSION);` prints out data when used in signup.php.

**PHP code for signup.php:**

```
all the codes are working correctly and data are getting stored correctly in MySQL db
$_SESSION['token'] = $token; 
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;  
 header("Location:http://mursali.com/Profile/test.php");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some hosts won't allow sessions. That could be the case for you if it's working locally. A good alternative is to use cookies and store traditional session data in a DB.

Comment: If a user logs in successfully, sessions are created and that works fine because they are used in `home.php`.

Comment: @nathan-dawson - If you ever find a host that doesn't allow sessions, then you change host.... because basically it's a host that doesn't allow you to have any kind of security at all on your site

Comment: are you SURE sessions are working - your explanation, although clear, doesn't actually show any proof they are working -> signup.php basically tries to set two $_SESSION variables then redirects - this would still work (and you could echo them out on the same page) even if sessions aren't working -> can you post your actual code for signup.php -> hide any database strings etc.

Comment: It's only for that page, `signup.php` that's having issue. Sessions gets created in `login.php` and it works fine.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest without some `code` to look at is that you might be calling / including an external resource that has session_start() in it (which can destroy an old session and create a new one) -> try using @session_start() everywhere and see if it fixes your problem - if it does remove it and find the offending session_start (as @session is deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call session_write_close() before each redirect to ensure the session has been written down and closed.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: Thanks, have just done that but it is still returning empty `Array ( )`.